# Render History AutoSave?

Tags: rendering

Is it possible for Blender to autosave each render into the Slots in the Render View Window?

Is this possible? Maybe an Addon is available? I also use VRay in 3ds max and it has a frame buffer which is really good for this - it helps massively when doing lookdev.

Thanks,
N

Comment: Hi. Please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask multiple questions but as separate posts. I suggest editing your question down to just one question (by using the [edit] link below it) and asking the other one separately. Also, please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: Hello :). [This](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/new-slots-system-in-render-view/731) is an interesting devtalk thread about improving render slots. It's still not implemented though.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to change slots every time you render (shortcut keys <kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>9</kbd> on the upper keyboard numbers).